# Pyplot - Label Plots

Tags: python, graphing, matplotlib

I am having a nightmare of a time trying to label data with pyplot.

I am currently plotting all of my data like this: plt.plot(data).

data is an array that has a column of total costs, and then other columns for sub costs

I would like to add a legend and label each of the data lists appropriately.  I can't seem to get the legend to work though.  plt.legend(('Column 1','Column 2','etc.) , loc =1) and other things like that did not work.  If I plot each column individually, it stops working correctly for some reason.

I look forward and thank you for any advice.

EDIT:

```
for i in range(1,days):
    data.append(totalCost(i)) #cost returns retVal, construction, gas, and wage
plt.ylabel('Cost in US Dollars') 
plt.title('Economic Cost over Time')

plt.plot(data)
plt.legend(('Total','Construction','Gas','Wage'),loc=1) # Legend is blank
```

EDIT 2:
Instead of having the code in different locations in my program, I reorganized it and centralized everything.  With those changes, the legend started working, and everything seems to be resolved.  I have no idea what the issue was though.

```
plt.plot(data)
plt.legend(('Total Cost', 'Construction Cost', 'Gas Cost','Wage Cost'),loc=0)
plt.grid(False)
plt.xlabel('Time (Days)')
plt.ylabel('Cost in US Dollars')
plt.title('Economic Cost over Time')
print ('   Close the Graph to Continue Using this Model')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you provide a more complete sample code? I have a hunch there's something wrong in the assignment of xdata and ydata. What should be the x-axis? What is the first column of data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code properly displays a legend, with Matplotlib 1.1 on Mac OS X, provided that:

- Matplotlib is put in interactive mode at the beginning: `plt.ion()`
- The code ends with `plt.show()`, for instance.

Upgrading Matplotlib might also help.

A last possible solution would be to indeed plot each line separately with its own label: `plt.plot(<single line data>, label='Construction')`, etc., and the plot the legend with `plt.legend(loc='best')`.

Comment: I am running python3.2 and a port of the most updated matplotlib so that it works with my 64-bit computer.

Comment: I have not yet tried ION, and when I plot the data on it's own, the displayed results are no longer accurate. All the lines go to zero in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Insted of passing headings inside plt.legend() u can create an list of legends and pass them to your plot ie,
    `legends = ['Total Cost', 'Construction Cost', 'Gas Cost','Wage Cost']
 plt.plot(data , labels = legends)
 plt.legend()`